# Dark/Mystery novel involving 3 transfer students. Two of them have psychic powers

Tags: story-identification, novel

- I read this long time back. Early 2000s. Don't remember the name or author.
- Main character is a high school girl named Lisa. She is popular, softhearted, friendly and good-natured. She has the highest ranking/grade in her school.
- It's been a month since a new student got transferred over to her school. But, he has somewhat of aggressive, cold and impassive nature. Therefore, he hasn't made any friends yet. But, he seems to want to keep it that way.
- Later on two other boys also get transferred to the same school. One was a shy, timid and a nerdy boy. The other one a jerk.
- One day for some reason the first transfer student was almost going to beat up the new shy transfer student but Lisa and other class mates intervene. The first student gets suspended for a bit or so I think. Since we don't hear about him for a while.
- Lisa also kinda helps out the shy transfer student as he starts to get picked on by the jerk transfer student.
- Couple of other things happen but I don't remember.
- Anyways, sometime later on, when she is trying to escape from the jerk transfer student, the shy transfer student comes. She is initially glad to see him but then to her horror he reveals that he and the jerk transfer student are working together.
- The shy transfer student is able to stop her body from moving psychically with his mind. He seems to have psychic powers.
- The "jerk transfer student", in pain with his injuries caused by Lisa while trying to escape, then groans towards the shy transfer student and tells him that maybe he should be playing the timid nerd role next time.
- The "shy transfer student" mockingly replies back, "Eh, get your shit together you big fu***** pussy."
- He reveals that the whole shy timid nerd and the jerk bully nerd thing his just an act to bait in dumb naive girls like her. "Me and that jerk make a great team don't we" he tells her laughingly.
- I think they both then start beating her up with a rod or something like that. And then rape her. And I think after they are done they actually give her to some street gang where she is gang raped by all of them. She is then dumped on the street lying unconsciously.
- When she wakes up the next day she is in the first transfer student home. It is revealed that the first transfer student encountered those two deranged students from his previous school.
- And the two deranged duo massacred everyone in that school. He was the only survivor of that incident. He lost his girlfriend and all his friends in that incident.
- From that point he started searching for all information and clues regarding the duo. He eventually learned that they always appear in a duo and they either massacre an entire school or rape one girl.
- The deranged duo also seemed to have the abilities to change their physical appearance. As a result the police haven't been able to capture them. So when the two new transfer students showed up in this school he knew it was them. And wanted to get them but was intervene by Lisa and the other class mates.
- He tries to convince Lisa to not get involved and waste her life on getting revenge for this duo anymore. But she is very firm on wanting her revenge so he agrees to work with her.
- I believe the book ends there and continues on the next one. I believe this is a 3 part novel. And this is the second one. I believe the first one details the first transfer student story. But, I have not read the first and the third novel. So, I am not entirely sure.